# How to Pause or Stop the callback function of Android Alarm Manager in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, alarmmanager

I am working on an Application wherein which I will have to pause or stop the callback function of Android Alarm Manager every time the user locks his phone.I dont know how to detect the user locks his phone as well.

I tried using Application life cycle management but the result for when the user both locks and minimises the App are one and the same.Below is the code.Please have a look:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'CommonPicker.dart';
import 'fileUtils.dart';
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';


void callback(){
  print("I am in the isolate");
  DateTime now=DateTime.now().toLocal();
 print("Date time:");
 print(now);
 //operation to be performed
  print("last line of Isolate");
}

class AlertTime2 extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/alertTime2';

  @override
  _AlertTime2State createState() => _AlertTime2State();
}

class _AlertTime2State extends State<AlertTime2> {
  String mm = "00";
  String ss = "00";
  var mmValue;
  var ssValue;
  var totalTimeInSec;
  String _selectedTime;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    FileUtils().readFromFile().then((String value) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedTime = value;
      });
    });
  }


  void alarm_managing_function(int t) async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
    await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(Duration(seconds: t), 0, callback);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 70, 0, 0),
          child: Text(
            "Timer for Notification",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 150, 0, 0),
          child: Text(
            "MM-SS",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Text(
            "${_selectedTime ?? 'Selected Time'}",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 38),
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            DatePicker.showPicker(context,
                showTitleActions: true,
                pickerModel:
                    CustomPicker(currentTime: DateTime.tryParse(_selectedTime)),
                onConfirm: (time) {
              setState(() {
                print(time);
                _selectedTime = DateFormat("mm-ss").format(time);
                FileUtils().saveToFile(_selectedTime);

                mm = _selectedTime.substring(0, 2);
                ss = _selectedTime.substring(3, 5);
                print(mm);
                print(ss);
                mmValue = int.parse(mm);
                ssValue = int.parse(ss);
                totalTimeInSec = mmValue * 60 + ssValue;
                print(totalTimeInSec);
                DateTime now=DateTime.now().toLocal();
                alarm_managing_function(totalTimeInSec);
              });
            }, locale: LocaleType.en);
          },
          child: Text("Show Time picker"),
        ),

        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have insert this line of code to stop or pause alarm

```
cancel = await AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(id);
```

pass the id of alarm that you want to stop.

Answer (score 0):

check my code , how to do it , in this code i did stop the AndroidAlarmManager and alaram

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
import 'package:android_alarm_manager_plus/android_alarm_manager_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ringtone_player/flutter_ringtone_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const AlarmManagerExampleApp());
}

class AlarmManagerExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AlarmManagerExampleApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0x9f4376f8),
      ),
      home: const _AlarmHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class _AlarmHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const _AlarmHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AlarmHomePageState createState() => _AlarmHomePageState();
}

class _AlarmHomePageState extends State<_AlarmHomePage> {
  int alarmId = 1;

  Future<void> scheduleAlarm() async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      const Duration(microseconds: 0),
      alarmId,
      callback,
      rescheduleOnReboot: true,
      exact: true,
      wakeup: true,
    );
  }

  Future<void> scheduleCancelAlarm() async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      const Duration(microseconds: 0),
      alarmId,
      stopcallback,
      rescheduleOnReboot: true,
      exact: true,
      wakeup: true,
    );
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static Future<void> callback() async {
    developer.log('Alarm fired!');
    FlutterRingtonePlayer.playAlarm(
      looping: true,
      asAlarm: false,
      volume: 1.0,
    );
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static Future<void> stopcallback() async {
    developer.log('Alarm stop!');
    AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(1);
    FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Android alarm manager plus example'),
        elevation: 4,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              scheduleCancelAlarm();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.stop),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Alarm fired  times',
              style: textStyle,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await scheduleAlarm();
              },
              child: const Text('Schedule OneShot Alarm'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```